# how should I write the script to install my own written software in Linux?

Tags: linux

So the question is pretty straightforward. My idea is pretty simple, just copy the executable under /usr, then add the path into the environment path variable.

Is that all? Or do I miss something?

Sorry if this question is dumb, I'm not a noob to Linux but I am not sure about this question.
I mean it's pretty much gonna work but I don't know if it's the "standard" way to do it.

Comment: If you want to check details -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419430/creating-an-installer-for-linux-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254054/best-approach-to-writing-a-generic-installer-for-a-linux-application, --- otherwise consider copying it to ~/bin/ and add that to your path for local use.

Comment: The default should be in [`/usr/local`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) unless the user specifies otherwise.  The rest of `/usr` is for things installed by the operating system (e.g. via the distribution's package manager).

Answer (score 5):

Don't write an install script at all.

Package it for the popular package managers or have someone package it for you.

The most popular are

- dpkg/apt used by Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint and friends
- rpm/yum used by RedHat Linux, openSUSE and fiends
- pacman used by ArchLinux and fiends
- emerge used by Gentoo and fiends

Answer (score 0):

Yep, all you need to do is copy the executable (as long as you have no dependencies). If you put it in `/usr/bin`, you don't need to modify the path, as it's in there by default.

Comment: I got it, so if I run any command, bash will search the /usr/bin to match it? I didn't notice this. Thanks.